# calculating percentage of subtotals in charts

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

I am working with the following dataset:

```
stD              Category            Month
repaired             1                 1
repaired             2                 1
not repaired         1                 1
repaired             1                 1
not repaired         2                 2
not repaired         1                 3
not repaired         2                 3
repaired             2                 3
```

I need to create a line chart which would display the percentage of only the repaired items per month in each category. For the purposes of the chart "Month" is the Category Group, and Status and Category as Series Groups. 
I use the following expression to calculate the percantage of repaired items :

```
 =count(Fields!stDescription.Value) / count(Fields!stDescription.Value, "Chart_CategoryGroup")
```

This however does not disply the % of repaired items per category, but % of repaired items in said category out of all repaired units (in all categories) per that month.

I am unable to figure out how to display the % of repaired items in particular categories, rather than as a % of the entire % of repaired units per that month.

Comment: Could you modify your dataset to return a new field that would have a value of 0 for not repaired and a 1 for repaired? That way you could set your value to something like SUM(Fields!NewField.Value,"Chart_Category") / COUNT(Fields!stDescription.Value, "Chart_CategoryGroup").